# Does muscle strength reduce the risk and problems of injury?

Tags: injury, legs, knees

I have injured knees due to a cycling accident last year in October. If I run for a significant distance, I can get a pain in my knee or back that forces me to stop. I'm pretty sedentary apart from this kind of exercise.

Given that I already have the injury is it a good idea to do weight exercises to strengthen my legs or should I rest entirely until my knees are fully healed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the knee injury and what you did for treatment recovery? There is a world of difference between a scraped knee, a dislocated patella, meniscus tear, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Recovering from injury is a tricky thing, especially for active people who want to get moving again. Strength exercises can definitely help with injury recovery, but not knowing the specifics of your situation, I'd definitely suggest seeing a professional, like a physiotherapist, for an assessment and recommendations.

My guess is that you'll need to start with bodyweight exercises, and look to strengthening your hips and your glutes in order to support you knees better. You should also make sure that you're stretching out those muscles. I've definitely found that keeping my posterior chain stretched helps with back pain associated with running.

Edit: you can't actually strengthen your ITB. Thanks!

Comment: To be accurate, the ITB is not a muscle to be strengthened.  The TFL and hip musculature can be strengthened to relieve problems with ITB syndrome, but that is not the same thing as strengthening the band.